# Is it overkill to use a service bus if all messages are sent locally?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, message-queue, messaging, servicebus

I have a mail reading service that reads every email from an inbox, parses it and inserts it into a database. The issue I'm running into is that there is no guarantee that I will be parsing the emails in order they were received (this is a business requirement). My fix for this would be to introduce some sort of queueing system. This way I would process the items in order they came in. This would also give me the benefit of decoupling my reading of the emails and parsing/inserting them in the database.

So my question is is it overkill to use a service bus (such as NServiceBus) if I only plan on sending messages locally? Meaning that the service that would be reading emails and the service that parses/inserts emails in the database would reside on the same machine.

Thank you.

Comment: If you know what order to add them to the queue in why can't you just change your logic to process the items in that order?

Comment: So you are thinking of having one service to read the e-mail, put it into a queue, and another service that reads the queue, and puts the information into the database?  If your current process right now isn't guaranteed to process the e-mails in the order they came in, I'm not sure how having it output to a queue is going to help...

Comment: @Ben - Good point. Due to issues out of my control some components may crash. If something crashes while processing the queue . This is pretty much a way to ensure that any failures in the system don't result in losing the email.

Comment: @Daryl - You're right. There are still some tweaks that need to be done in order to ensure messages are processed in order. The idea is that I would serialize all emails that come through and persist them on disk. Then I could possibly use something as simple as `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor for new items added to the queue. The issue with having one service do all of the heavy lifting is that if worse comes to worse and the server goes down then everything that is in the memory queue is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is clearly overkill, **especially since NServiceBus doesn't guarantee that messages are delivered in order**.

You can just use a `Queue<T>`, assuming you know how to get the messages out in order (this appears to be where you are having trouble, not that you are or aren't using a queue or whatever; you have to know how to get the items into the queue in the right order to begin with).

KISS and YAGNI apply here, all day, every day.

Comment: 1000x yes.  Too rarely do we see clear yes and no answers on here.  This is a definite case for a straight answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would just us an MSMQ for your persistence issues.  Once it's in, it's guaranteed to be there, regardless of the machine losing power, or some other application crashing.

Answer (score 1):

The *would* word I dont't like. In my opinion: make your system as much flexible as it possible, without affecting limits of acceptable performance of your application (that only you may know).

In general: be prepared to worst marketing decision you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. For your application, I agree with Jason, a service bus will not help you process messages in order any more than a local data structure will. And, as Jason said, it will most likely be *more* difficult considering the order of messages in a service bus is not guaranteed.

However, sending messages locally with a service bus can be very useful. It makes it very easy to send messages to other processes asynchronously. Since the consumer of the message is in a different process, you don't really have any threading concerns. Messages can be durable so you don't have to worry about something being missed, and it's very easy to add additional processing for a message after-the-fact by just adding a new subscriber. As an extra bonus, if the system ever becomes too big to run comfortable on one machine, it would be trivial to distribute the bus.

For your solution, it is unnecessary and might even cause issues. But there are cases where it makes sense to use a service bus locally.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of job where ZeroMQ works well, and the side benefit to you is that you learn how to use a tool which can be used with other languages and on other platforms as well.